# Nested subscription in Angular - performance issue?

Tags: angular, subscription

I have a `subscription` to store and base on the value from the store, a call to a service is made which I `subscribe` to further.

Does nested subscription cause performance issue? Although `onDestroy` the `subscription` is destroyed.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
  this.statesubscription = this.contentServerStore
    .pipe(select(getContentServerState))
    .subscribe(val => {
      if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(val) &&
        val.region.toUpperCase() == Constants.region.us
      ) {
        let contentRequest = new ContentRequest();
        this.regionService.getRegion(contentRequest).subscribe(region => {
          if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(region)) {
            this.regionContent = <string>this.domSanitizer
              .bypassSecurityTrustHtml(region[Constants.regionKey]);
          }
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: You will not notice and issues with the above code but try to use `flatMap` operator within pipe  for better performance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the flatMap operator for nesting subscriptions.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    this.statesubscription = this.regionService.getRegion(contentRequest).flatMap(region => this.contentServiceFunc(region)).subscribe()
}

private contentServiceFunc(region) {
    return this.contentServerStore.pipe(select(getContentServerState))
        .subscribe(val => {
            if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(val) &&
                val.region.toUpperCase() == Constants.region.us
            ) {
                let contentRequest = new ContentRequest();

                if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(region)) {
                    this.regionContent = < string > this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(region[Constants.regionKey]);
                }
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but here we are missing the call to service after validating from store.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. `subscribe`bing in a nested fashion like the way you're doing is definitely an anti-pattern.

You can probably try using [**`map`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and [**`switchMap`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operators along with an [**`async`**](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template to achieve this.

Here, give this a try:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
  this.regionContent$ = this.contentServerStore
    .pipe(
      select(getContentServerState),
      map(val => {
        if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(val) &&
          val.region.toUpperCase() == Constants.region.us
        ) {
          let contentRequest = new ContentRequest();
          return this.regionService.getRegion(contentRequest)
            .pipe(
              switchMap(region => {
                if (!this.checkValuesService.isNullOrUndefined(region)) {
                  return <string > this.domSanitizer
                    .bypassSecurityTrustHtml(region[Constants.regionKey]);
                } else {
                  return of(`<h1>No Content Found!</h1>`);
                }
              })
            );
        }
      })
    );
}
```

In the template you could do something like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="regionContent$ | async"></div>
```

**PS:** I haven't really tried this, but should probably work.